# What is the universal runtime component #ifdef for windows (UWP) not iOS?

Tags: c++, uwp

I'm trying to build a universal runtime component using cross-platform C++ code in a git submodule. I need to figure out what the `#ifdef` is for when I want code to build for the universal runtime component (UWP) and not for xcode on iOS.

```
#ifdef __WINDOWS_ONLY_COMPILE_FLAG?
    // some code i want to compile on windows
#endif
```

Comment: Are you asking what preprocessor definition can be used to identify a Windows build? It depends on your compiler.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yeah thats what i'm asking... didn't know the name of it

Comment: It depends on your compiler or IDE. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) for the predefined macros for Visual Studio.

Comment: I see `_WIN32` most often

Answer (score 3):

By default, Universal Windows projects get the `WINDOWS_UWP` compiler directive defined.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Could you please include a source from docs etc?

Comment: @Shimmy I couldn't find any specific link for this, but found 2 related references: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/cross-platform-targeting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/building-cross-platform-applications/platform-divergence-abstraction-divergent-implementation

Comment: Tried googling for that and couldn't find any. You rock. Thank you!

Comment: Those references are both for C#, is it still the same for C++ (what the question is asking)?